# Having Issues with Magic Static Functions

Tags: php

I have a class that I'm trying to create a function that will call a static method that is run through a magic method.  The thing is the functions work as long as they are from different types of classes than the class calling them, but if I call a static function of the same class all the function will return is 1.

```
class Test {
    public function static __callStatic($name, $params) {
        return 2;
    }
    public function __call($name, $params) {
        return 1;
    }
    public function Test1() {
        return Test::GetTwo(); 
    }
}
class Test2 {
   public function Test() {
       return Test::GetTwo();
   }
}
$t = new Test();
echo $t->Test1(); //prints 1 should be 2
$t2 = new Test2();
echo $t->Test(); //prints 2 as it should
```

even if the static method GetTwo() returns an object I still get 1 if I'm calling a function in the same scope as Test1().  Any one else run into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo Test::Test1();
```

You don't need (nor should use) an instance to call a static method. Use the class and the scope resolution operator (::) to do the call.

If you need [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) use `static::Test1();`

For an method call on an instance, PHP will try the following:

1. Find an instance method named X.
2. Find a magic method __call.
3. Find a class (static) method named X.
4. Find a magic class (static) method __callStatic.

In your case, it finds __call at step 2 and goes with that.

Comment: looks like that is what is happening for the time being I'm going to put in a redirect in the __call function to run __callStatic.  Thought that it would know it was trying to call a static so would try __callStatic first.

Comment: looks like so far the redirect works, so thanks for pointing out the order of how PHP finds functions it helped me find the solution so I'll give you the answer.

Comment: We use self::$variable to call static of current class. Not, className::$variable

Comment: @web2students.com self only works from within the class, but not outside it.